# Re-enter cisco vpn passwords

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager, vpn

Since I upgraded from Lubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 my VPN passwords have to be re-entered every time I open the VPN connection.

The passwords used to be maintained by the key ring but no longer. When I create a new configuration using Cisco Compatible VPN (vpnc) it looks like it is storing the passwords in the keyring. A popup appears and asks for my password.

Any body any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding the connection?

Comment: Thank you Braiam, I did, but unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is what went wrong.

After I upgraded from Lubuntu 13.10 to 14.4 the network manager was missing in my panel. I solved this by adding nm-applet --sm-enable & in my .profile. At first this seemed to be a good solution, the network manager reappeared again. But the problem mentioned above occurred.

What I should have done to get my network manager back again is select *Preferences* -> *Default applications for LXSessions*. Click the tab *Autostart* and type after *+ Add* "nm-applet". Then click *+ Add*. After logging on again the network manager is where one would expect it to be and Keyring will work as well to fill in the stored passwords.

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html

Cheers.